# MsBuild and include projectreference target

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, frameworks

I have self target and its started 'beforebuild'. Target include projectreference of target project before build/rebuild. It's work only if I firstible clean project and build. Any ideas?

My target backendconfig.targets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="AddCoreBackendConfig" AfterTargets="SetCoreBackendConfig">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ProjectReference Include="..\ChoiceProject.Core\ChoiceProject.Core.csproj">
                <Project>{590E7363-8CD9-4AFA-1111-D70ECE33DE7D}</Project>
                <Name>ChoiceProject.Core</Name>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

and Csproj of this project:

```
<None Include="Properties\backendconfig.targets" />


<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="Assemble" />
    <CallTarget Targets="SetCoreBackendConfig" />
    <CallTarget Targets="AddCoreBackendConfig" />
  </Target>
```

If I change project in include and I build that will be not create .dll core file. I must clean project first. Why?

Comment: Try changing to `<Target Name="Before" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">`. (Overriding the `BeforeBuild` target should work but in quick testing there seems to be an issue.)

Comment: It's resolved. Close.